# Capture WKWebView audio for metering

Tags: ios, audio, iframe, core-audio, wkwebview

I am currently working on an app that contains a `WKWebView` in which I have loaded an iFrame with video streaming from YouTube.

I would like to be able to create an audio visualizer that is shown alongside this iFrame and moves in reaction to the audio from the stream.

I have been following along with [this Ray Wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/36475/how-to-make-a-music-visualizer-in-ios) for creating a music visualizer, but the tutorial uses the `setMeteringEnabled` and `updateMeters` functions built in to `AVAudioPlayer`.

Is there any way to meter audio coming from a `WKWebView`? I just want an average volume level, not the actual audio stream itself.

I have attempted to look at libraries like [The Amazing Audio Engine](https://github.com/TheAmazingAudioEngine/TheAmazingAudioEngine), but none of them seem to allow you to capture the channel coming from the `WKWebView` at all, let alone for metering purposes.